# NSPredicate for NSNumber Contains NSNumber (as NSString)

Tags: ios, search-engine, nspredicate

Simple approach: I have a `SearchView` where the user can select some CoreDate and he can search for `Name`, `City` (both `NSString`) and `Clientnumber` (`NSNumber`)

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[cd] %@ OR City contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText,searchText];
```

This is my predicate for Name and City, but how can I search for a searchquery within an `NSNumber`field?

So if I would search for *300*, it should return entries with `Clientnumber`: 300123 and 1230012, because both **contains** the **300**.

So, how can I do this? Is it possible to "convert" the value for `Clientnumber` within the `NSPredicate` to `NSString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `CAST(Clientnumber, 'NSString') contains[cd] %@` to do this search:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                            predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[cd] %@ OR City contains[cd] %@ OR CAST(Clientnumber, 'NSString') contains[cd] %@",
                            searchText,searchText,searchText];
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can you provide the source where you read about this method? I want to read more about it. Thank you.

Comment: It's a shame that Realm doesn't support the CAST method

Answer (score 0):

I found that dasblineklight's answer wouldn't work for me in a core data search using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. What DID work however was passing `number.description` as the name of the property, so for this specific case that would be:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[cd] %@ OR City contains[cd] %@ OR Clientnumber.description contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText, searchText, searchText];
```